# How to describe "the English letter Q" in words

Tags: sentence-construction, grammaticality

As a learner I am having problem answering the question:

> How to make English capital **Q** ?

in words.

> Answer: **First, draw a circle then...**

I am not able to describe the **small line** that points outward .

Please help me describe it.

By the way, can I use the verb **curl** to describe the letter **S?**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

We call this small line the **tail** of the Q. Here is an example from [the "Q" Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q#Typography):

> Depending on the typeface used to typeset the letter Q, the letter's **tail** may either bisect its bowl as in Helvetica, meet the bowl as in Univers, or lie completely outside the bowl as in PT Sans.

When you are drawing a Q by hand, the tail of the Q usually crosses from the inside of the circle to the outside. Like this:

[image: capital letter Q with bisecting tail]

If you want to describe how to draw the tail, you could say something like this:

> First, draw a circle. Then, in the bottom-right, draw a short line across the border of the circle.

Comment: What about "S"?

Comment: @user100323 That is technically a separate question... you could say that the top part of the S and the bottom part of the S _curl_ in opposite directions. (This is _curl_ used as a verb, rather than as a noun: "To assume a spiral or curved shape.") But I am not sure if that works as a full description of the letter's shape.

Comment: @user100323 Usually, we take the shape of the letter S for granted, and use it to describe the shape of _other_ objects. (https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/S-shaped) Describing the shape of the S itself is surprisingly difficult, partly because we're not accustomed to doing it. More generally, I think open-ended curves are harder to describe in words than circles or straight lines.